# Why doesn't Joomla show assigned JoomShopping modules on SEF URLs?

Tags: joomla-3.x, module-display, sef

I have site which is build on JoomShopping module almost entirely. JoomShopping Search module assigned to all pages, and positioned on the left.

Then I have enabled SEF urls. If I visit site by the SEF url (`/index.php/category`), then search module won't be shown on pages anymore. But still will be shown on the same page retrieved by the full url (`index.php?option=com_jshopping&controller=category`).

Why can it be this way?

Comment: How are you creating the SEF urls?

Comment: I suggest checking whether JoomShopping has a SEF plugin that needs to be installed and/or enabled.